# How to catch errors that happen when showing an Angular dynamic component?

Tags: angular

I have a component to display notifications. It has a `ViewChild` that has a `ViewContainerRef`.

Based on the type of notification, I display different components in place of that viewChild. This is the code to create and add the component based on the notification type:

```js
private loadInappNotificationItem(messageType: MessageType): void {
  const inappNotificationItemComponent: Type<IInappNotificationItemComponent>
    = this.inappNotificationItemMapping.get(messageType);
  if (inappNotificationItemComponent === undefined) {
    this.hasCustomComponent = false;
    return;
  }

  const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<IInappNotificationItemComponent> =
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(inappNotificationItemComponent);

  this.hasCustomComponent = true;
  const viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef = this.inappNotificationItemHost.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();

  const componentRef: ComponentRef<IInappNotificationItemComponent> =
    viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

  const component: IInappNotificationItemComponent = componentRef.instance;
  component.notification = this.notification;
}
```

This works as intended, but now i'd like to show a fallback component, if anything goes bad when displaying the notification component (for example when the structure of the notification property is wrong).

For this i'd need to be able to register a function somewhere, that is called when displaying the viewChild failed for some reason, so that i can then remove it and display a fallback.

I know that i can register a custom ErrorHandler on the Module that contains the component, and i can catch the Errors i'd like to catch there, but in that handler i have no reference to the notification component whose viewChild failed to display.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to write a class-decorator that will catch every error in every method of my component class, which in turn allowed me to display the fallback when anything in my component class throws an error.
Sure, i'd need to decorate all custom components with this, but that's ok, as long as i only need to add this one decorator. (See my [my partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523883/3213368))

This however did not help with Errors that originate from the template! For example, when accessing a property in the custom components template, that doesn't exist. So, another question that might help solve this one is:
**how do i catch runtime template errors IN my component** (not globally or on module level, as i don't have a reference to the broken component there)

Comment: Just add `@Output() public failure: EventEmitter` and have the component emit when something is wrong. If you are referring to JavaScript run-time errors, then that is a different solution.

Comment: @Reactgular Thanks for the hint, but i'd also like to handle JS runtime errors, because i can't anticipate what they will be, and want to make sure that displaying the notifications definitely works all the time, even if some of them use a fallback for some reason.

Comment: Can you further detail what you mean by **"is called when displaying the viewChild failed for some reason"**? Do you mean something in your dynamic component doesn't render as intended or that some off the wall error happens in the Angular code and an error occurs when trying to render a viewChild element?

Comment: @Narm the latter. i know that there won't be a generic catch-all solution for when the component doesn't render as intended. But if angular throws an error, which results in my component not being displayed at all (for example if i cause a JS-Error in the ngOnInit or something), then i want to be able to catch that, remove the custom viewChild and render a fallback instead.

Comment: Can custom event be an option for you ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 1):

> @Neutrosider If you refere to random js erros generated by your app code what I would do is eighther wrap the angular hooks from those components into try {} catch statements but this does not look nice. Or create some typescript custom annotations which will act something like this

```
interface ErrorHandledComponent {
    isInErrorState: boolean;
}

export function HandleComponentErrors() {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const oriiginalHook = target[propertyKey].bind(target);
        target[propertyKey] = (...args) => {
            try {
                oriiginalHook(...args)
            } catch (e) {
                if (isDevMode) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
                target.isInErrorState = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
@Component({
....
template: `<ng-container *ngIf="!isInErrorState">...content<ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="isInErrorState">...error content<ng-container>`
})
export class CumponentWithErrorHandling implements {
   isInErrorState: boolean;
   @HandleComponentErrors()
   ngOnInit() {
   ...your custom code
   }
}
```

> And basicly annotate all the angular hooks if that's what you are
>   trying to achieve then you will have a nice render for a js error
>   inside your code implementation or maybe dispatch the error further or
>   log it to your backend. I hope it helps

Comment: I will try if this works good enough for me before the bounty ends

Comment: Why use @annotation function to handle error when accessed on custom code and `ngOnInit` func. When i wrote ...!. Can't use try-catch on `ngOnInit()` and send to ErrorService

Comment: @Nicu i was able to create a class-decorator that catches all JS-Errors in every function of my component class, and if one happens, it replaces itself with my fallback. This works, but only for errors in my component class. This does not work for Errors in my template (for example accessing a non-existent property)

Comment: @Neutrosider Nice I didn't thaught of adding an extra decorator to the class it would be nice if you post your answer to have a reference for future questions

Answer (score 0):

If you call any method like API calls, then if you want to see the error if occurs, use below format.....i used

```
this.customerService.deleteAll()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.reloadData();
    },
    error => console.log('ERROR: ' + error));
```

It generates logs at the console in devTool of browser

Answer (score 0):

**partial answer**

The following answer will work for all errors that happen in the components class. it will however not catch errors happening in the template (for example accessing a nonexistent property).
This answer is inspired by the [answer from @Nicu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56479310/3213368)

Here's a class decorator, that will wrap every method of the decorated class in a try-catch, so that the error can be handled somewhere else

```js
export function CatchErrors(): Function {

  return (decoratedClass): any => {
    // find the names of all methods of that class
    const properties: Array<string> = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(decoratedClass.prototype);
    const methodsNames = properties.filter((propertyName): boolean => {
      return typeof decoratedClass.prototype[propertyName] === 'function';
    });

    // wrap every method in a try-catch
    console.log(properties, methodsNames);
    for (const methodsName of methodsNames) {
      decoratedClass.prototype[methodsName] = new Proxy(decoratedClass.prototype[methodsName], {
        apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList): void => {
          try {
            return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
          } catch (error) {
            console.warn(`calling ${methodsName} on ${decoratedClass.name} failed`, error);
            for (const callback of decoratedClass.__jsErrorCallbacks) {
              callback(error);
            }
          }
        },
      });
    }

    // add a method to register callbacks, that should be executed if something goes wrong
    decoratedClass.__jsErrorCallbacks = [];
    decoratedClass.prototype.__onJSError = (callback): void => {
      decoratedClass.__jsErrorCallbacks.push(callback);
    };
  };
}
```

Then we just need to add that decorator to our component:

```js
import {CatchErrors} from './somewhere';

@CatchErrors()
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: 'some-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['some-component.component.scss'],
})
export class SomeComponent {
  /* ...*/
}
```

And lastly, we can react in the parents component.
(most of the code is copied from the original question, just for context):

```js
// THIS PART IS COPIED FROM THE ORIGINAL QUESTION
private loadInappNotificationItem(messageType: MessageType): void {
  const inappNotificationItemComponent: Type<IInappNotificationItemComponent>
    = this.inappNotificationItemMapping.get(messageType);
  if (inappNotificationItemComponent === undefined) {
    this.hasCustomComponent = false;
    return;
  }

  const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<IInappNotificationItemComponent> =
    this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(inappNotificationItemComponent);

  this.hasCustomComponent = true;
  const viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef = this.inappNotificationItemHost.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();

  const componentRef: ComponentRef<IInappNotificationItemComponent> =
    viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

  const component: IInappNotificationItemComponent = componentRef.instance;

  // THIS IS THE INTERESTING PART
  // ------------------------
  if (component.__onJSError !== undefined) {
    component.__onJSError((error): void => {
      console.log(`replacing custom component for ${this.notification} with fallback`);
      viewContainerRef.clear();
      this.hasCustomComponent = false;
    });
  }
  // ------------------------

  component.notification = this.notification;
}
```